# like operator in ngresource of angularjs

Tags: angularjs, mongodb, ngresource

I use Loopback with node to query MongoDB via ngresource of AngularJS.

I wish to implement autocomplete.

Product is my ngResource

```
Product.find({filter:{where:{name:'search string'}, limit:10}})
```

The above code only search for 'search string' (Not all matching elements)
Like

```
'search string2'
'search string1'
'search string3'
```

How to search equivalent to mongoDB's

```
db.Product.find({name:/.*search string*/});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the like operator in your query filter object :

```
{filter: 
  where: {myField: {like: '.*search string.*'}}
}
```

And that will do the trick.