# Restangular getList() using wildcard or a not operator

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mongodb, restangular

I am trying to query a specific data using Restangular with MongoDb.
I have on my controller:

```
$scope.movies = Movie.getList({name: "Graceland"}).$object;
```

Once I do this, I can retrieve the data. However, I would like to use more resources like a wild card or a not operator. Something like this:

```
$scope.movies = Movie.getList({name: !"Graceland"}).$object;
```

or

```
$scope.movies = Movie.getList({name: "Graceland*"}).$object;
```

Then, I would retrieve all data having "Graceland" in the beginning or all data different from "Graceland". Does anyone have any clue how to implement it, please?  thankyou very much.

Comment: There is also a lot of related question already answered in stackoverflow.

Comment: I do not agree. I did a research, but I couldn't find an answer for my case.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/28447838/783219 try `$scope.movies = Movie.getList({filter:{where:{name:{like: 'Graceland*'}}}}).$object;`. If this works a bit of debug (or trial-and-error) can uncover the negation version (`{filter:{where:{name:{ne: 'Graceland'}}}}` maybe).

Comment: It doesn't work probably for being the MongoDB syntax. When it has db.name.find().

Answer (score 0):

First of all:

- I never used mongobd;
- Usually will put this as a comment but since it is long I will use a answer to better format it;

Sorry.

---

I will suggest you to look at:

- https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/crud-introduction/
- https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/sql-comparison/#select
- https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/

On the mongodb manual you will also find more reference material that can be quite useful.

---

Instead of

```
$scope.movies = Movie.getList({name: !"Graceland"}).$object;
```

try

```
$scope.movies = Movie.getList({name: { $ne: "Graceland" }}).$object;
```

And instead of

```
$scope.movies = Movie.getList({name: "Graceland*"}).$object;
```

try

```
$scope.movies = Movie.getList({name: /Graceland.*/}).$object;
// or
$scope.movies = Movie.getList({name: { $regex: 'Graceland.*' }}).$object;
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, but it seems that Restangular does not support these kinds of syntax used on MongoDB. Maybe, Restangular has another one.

Comment: Sorry. Didn't notice that tag.